# How can i have multiple button in the header with react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can i put All and Favorites button in the header while using react-navigation?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`headerTitle`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#headerTitle) prop to render any custom component to use in your header.

> **headerTitle**
>
> String or React Element used by the header. Defaults to scene title

```
export const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: <MyCustomComponent />
    }
  },
  Profile: { screen: Profile }
});
```

Comment: care to provide example ?

Comment: @JP. added a mall example

Comment: Where's the example ?

Comment: @Heisen-Berg answer

Comment: Ok, but can you provide your `MyCustomComponent` ?

Comment: @Heisen-Berg sorry can't because I don't have any. I was giving a way to achieve the desired look. I don't really have any component looks like that. You need to create it yourself.